# Как уничтожить повторяющиеся в строке слова

Tags: python-3.x

Дано строку символов, которая состоит из отдельных слов, разделённых пробелом. Напечатать эту же последовательность слов, но при этом уничтожить все слова, которые повторяются

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# string = "яблоко груша вишня слива киви банан груша смородина яблоко слива"

string = input("Введите слова через пробел: ")

def destroy_repeat_word_in_string(data):
    new_string = set(data.split(' '))
    processed_string = " ".join([i for i in new_string])
    return processed_string

print(destroy_repeat_word_in_string(string))
```

Comment: А в случае, если слова надо вводить из input?

Comment: Яр1409: А если не секрет что у вас там за программа ?)

Comment: Что-то усложнили вы код... Весь код описывается в строку: `' '.join(set(data.split()))`. Например, `processed_string` можно просто через генератор списка заполнить: `processed_string = [i for i in new_string]` или еще короче: `processed_string = list(new_string)`. Но как выше написал, нет смысла гонять код из множества в список, чтобы применить join.

Comment: gil9red: Я так на скорую руку) Исправлено.

Answer (score 5):

1.Распарсить строку

2.Превратить список в множество

код:

```
print(set('1 2 3'.split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы напечатать уникальные слова из текста, сохраняя исходный порядок слов:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

text = input('Enter words')
print(*OrderedDict.fromkeys(text.split()))
```